# Using HTML attributes alt & title for a image

Tags: html

I would like to insert a image for a description for my site because of the font quality. I am wondering if I put in description in the `title` or `alt` attribute inside of the `img` element will it be the same for search engines if it was just text?

Answer (score 1):

The `alt` tag makes your code valid if it is xhtml document and also useful in terms of SEO. Also if image is not found, the `alt` text will be shown instead of the image. The `title` attribute is useful; a tooltip telling you about the image description when you move your move over it.

**Check out:**

- [Proper Use of ALT and TITLE Attributes](http://fadtastic.net/2007/04/19/proper-use-of-alt-and-title-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in the alt then yes this should be true.